# how to handle system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception failed recipients

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendmail, smtpclient

I wanna send email to multiple addresses (more than 1000 users) and use the following code, when I use it to send email to less than 100 users it works, but for more than 100 users it does not work and throw smtpfailedrecipientsexception failed recipients! why? how can I send email to valid addresses and get ride of this error?

```
public void SendMailMessage (string[] to,string message,string subject) 
    {
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage ();
        int lenght = to.GetLength(0);
        if (lenght > 1) {
            foreach (string email in to) {
                mMailMessage.Bcc.Add ( email );
            }
        }
        else {
            mMailMessage.To.Add ( to[0] );
        }

                mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress ("no-replay@mycompany.net");                  
                SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient ();
                mMailMessage.Body = message;
                mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;                
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s,X509Certificate certificate,X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {return true;};                    
            try {  
                mSmtpClient.Send (mMailMessage);                
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex){
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
            {
                SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
                if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                    status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    //client.Send(message);
                    mSmtpClient.Send (mMailMessage);

                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Debug (string.Format ("Failed to deliver message to {0},{1}", ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient, i));

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Debug (string.Format("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}", ex.ToString() ));
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am working on a very similiar problem,too. did you solve your problem? When inspecting my task I found, that some mailServers limit the number of mails that can be send on a daily base.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SMTP server that you are using is rejecting mails that have more then 100 recepients.

You can:

- use distribution lists instead of sending message to each recipient directly
- send multiple messages with no more than 100 recipients
- talk to admin of this server to change the limit

But be aware, that when you are sending messages to hundred of external recipients, spam filters would probably flag them as spam.

Comment: thank you @alex. But you know, when I send email to more than 100 users I got Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender which include this message : "This is the mail system at host mail.net.
I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message." however there are some valid email addresses in list of  mail addresses

Comment: Moreover, I think there are some invalid email address in my list which cause it throw this execption, isn't it?

Comment: @Farhad: you can batch the emails in hundreds and process them from a windows service so that you do not have to send them in a single stroke and the windows service will take care of processing the batch as you may require even more emails to be sent at a time,

Answer (score 0):

I found this in one of the Microsoft documentation that exception handled like following:

```
 var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
            {
                SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
                if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                    status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to deliver message to {0}",
                        ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}",
                    ex.ToString());
        }
```

But i don't know how to generate exception scenario for this exception
[Microsoft link - for mode details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpexception.statuscode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Mail_SmtpException_StatusCode)